# Мультисервер для файлов

Tags: файлы, файловая-система, загрузка

Доброго времени суток.

Сразу к делу. Собственно, есть файлообменник, он сделан обычным сайтом на обычном сервере, где хостятся еще куча сайтов. Суть не в этом. Есть задача сделать загрузку файлов не только на один сервер, а на несколько. Вот собственно вопрос:
Какой алгоритм мультисервера лучше использовать или как файлу дать понять, на какой сервер ему загружаться, или просто загружать файлы на сервер, пока не закончиться его дисковое пространство, а потом загружать следующий? Спрашиваю потому, что ранее с этим не сталкивался. Как бы поступили вы? Server 1 = 1TB, S2 = 3TB, S3=4TB etc... Собственно, может, есть алгоритм распределения файлов или ... Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Можно посмотреть, какие алгоритмы используются для [разбивания пространства ключей в распределённых хэш-таблицах (DHT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_hash_table#Keyspace_partitioning). DHT могут быть использованы в создании распределённой файловой системы, такой как [Tahoe: A Secure Distributed Filesystem](https://tahoe-lafs.org/~warner/pycon-tahoe.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделать функцию на псевдорандоме, которая выдает сервер с вероятностью, соответствующей его мощностям (оставшееся свободное место, средняя занятость канала). Ссылки на файлы сразу генерировать в виде serverXXX.obmen.failov.com, который будут вести на вебморду конкретного сервера. Всё.

Comment: Почему псевдорандом? Если анализировать канал и свободное место, это уже не рандом, это анализ данных и размещение файлов. Рандом - это случайный выбор. Так называемы хаос, энтропия. Но за ответ благодарю, мне приятно.

Comment: @KRUZER, потому что после анализа данных мы получим некоторые соотношения серверов, среди которых всё равно надо выбирать случайный, иначе будет вероятность того, что придут десять юзеров, им всем выпадет один самый свободный сервак, которому они тут же и забьют начисто канал, в то время как остальные будут простаивать. Ну и еще надо не забыть про то, что на серваках должен оставаться какой-то хедрум, и серваки с заполненостью > 90% должны выбывать из списка доступных на закачку вообще.

Comment: Да, вы меня убедили, благодарю вас.